# Cannot export video file in correct resolution

Tags: premiere

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4elrY4adr8) on how to cut out audio from my video (I actually wanted to cut out just part of audio but i know how to do that so its not a problem)
@ 2:55 the video shows a window which does not appear when i drag and drop my video in. :(
however when i right click on my video bar and click properties it still says the video is 480x800

However when i try to export the video the resolution of the original video appears as 720x480
In addition when i go to `sequence>sequence settings` the video frame is grayed out at 720 and 480 so i cannot change the settings.

When i try to export the video in the 480x800 resolution it just appears as a small video in the middle with whole bunch of black space around it.

I just want my exported video to be the same as the original video but i cant figure out how to do that.

Im using adobe premiere-cs6 but i need 50 more reputation to create that tag.

Comment: How are you exporting from Premiere? Is it through `File > Export > Media` (which is the correct way to export). This sort of clarity in your question will help get more answers.

Comment: yes that is exactly how im doing it

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you want to remove the audio from a video clip, using Premiere.

Start a new sequence, and drop your clip into it. There should be audio and video streams in the timeline.

Using `File > Export > Media`, there is a very simple way to remove the audio.

[image: Premiere's Export window allows you to select whether to export video and/or audio]

Using these toggles here, you can disable audio from being included in the export.

However, you will also want to make sure that your export settings are the same as the video clip.

[image: Premiere's Export window has video codec settings]

As for setting a codec, I suggest either:

1. Format: QuickTime / Codec: Animation - if you need a high-quality, large file size video for further editing.
2. Format: QuickTime / Codec: H.264 - if you need a file ready for playback, distribution, or internet upload.

Comment: did you read my question? I already know how to remove audio from a video (or part of audio in this case) my problem is that when i export the video I cannot export it in the correct resolution. (480 x 800) No matter what codec i use it comes out wrong

Comment: @Xitcod13 Under "basic video settings", you can set your desired resolution, as stated in my answer. Did this work for you? Are you able to post screenshots of your Export Settings window, please? It will help us narrow down your problem.